# Vertically Centered Crossbars

Tags: font-recommendation

I've been searching for a font with vertically centered crossbars but cannot find what I'm looking for. Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific, as there are no end of fonts that have vertically centered crossbars. [Here's just one example.](https://www.dafont.com/squarefont.font)

Comment: Thanks! Great suggestion!